# Obtaining each set (hyperedge) in a set system (hypergraph) as a union of sets in a smaller set sytem

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $V$ be a set and $E$ a set of subsets of $V$.  I'd like to know the proper terminology for the following concept.

Let me call it "generator".  A generator is a set $F$ of subsets of $V$ such that every $e \in E$ is the union of elements of $F$.  (No intersections allowed.)

(One is then interested in finding properties of "generators" of $(V,E)$, e.g., for finite $V$, the minimum cardinality of a "generator" $F$.)

Comment: This isn't an answer but I think we can translate the question to algebras as follows. Let V={x_1,x_2...} then let and edge be labeled by the vertices it contains. Then you are looking for squarefree monomial algebras that contain the algebra k[e_1,...] in their radical. Maybe this would give a new way to view the problem.

Comment: The terminology varies.  One use I like is that F is a base. One has to take care that it is a base with (respect to) operation union.  You can search the literature on union-closed sets for more examples of terminology.  Papers that cite  Poonen (1990 or1992; I'm not sure of the date) are a good start.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is equivalent to the following. In the strong group testing model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing) are goal is to identify some defective elements, that can be any set of a given closed system $D$, or maybe they are not, in which case we only have to output that they are not. In the non-adaptive model, we have to give our questions in advance, each of which is a set, and the answer is yes if and only if it contains a defective element. It was noticed by Peter Damaschke and it is not hard to prove that a set of questions solves the problem if and only if the complement of any element of $D$ can be covered by a union of them. So if $D=\{ V\setminus e \mid e\in E\}$, then we get exactly your problem.